# Can backward induction be used to solve any game?

Tags: game-theory

I'm new to game theory and I would like to know, if you can model any game through a payoff tree, couldn't you find the subgame perfect equillibrium for all games through backward induction?

Comment: This is a reasonable question, but it would be more appropriate at math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

No, backward induction can only be used when you have a finite dynamic game. A common example that you cannot use backward induction is the "Rubinstein infinite horizon bargaining game".

Comment: Sorry if this sounds basic, but could you provide a definition for a dynamic game?

Comment: A sequential (Dynamic) game is a game where one player chooses their action before the others choose theirs. i.e. all players are not taking actions simultaneously.